# Powershell Regex check for string between brackets

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to read values from a text file into a hashtable, I want to be able to be able to tell when I encounter a value that has the format "['somestring']"... So when I encounter a value that has brackets around it I want to store the string into a specific variable and run a function with that string.

I was thinking that regex was the way to go for this but I am unsure what a possible regex value would look like. Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$r = [regex] "\[([^\[]*)\]"
$match = $r.match("[somestring]")
$text = $match.groups[1].value
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if("['somestring']" -match "\['([^\]]+)'\]")
{
    $matches[1]
}
```