# Parse a report with powershell

Tags: parsing, powershell

I'm trying to gather some statistics using powershell.

I have about 4,000 reports that look like this (all in their own Report.txt files - some have more fields. I've sniped it):

What I would like to do (thinking out loud) is take each [  ] and make that a csv header and then add each item under that header under it. Then I can run simple count statements against it and pull out some data. Maybe there is a better/easier way?

The idea is to have some like:

Requested Permissions: android.permission.INTERNET 3,562 of 4,000
Requested Permissions: android.permission.READ_SMS 1 of 4,000
etc...

So far i've stripped down the string so it no longer has white spaces and *.

```
[ Package name ]
 * com.software.application

[ Requested Permissions ]
 * android.permission.INTERNET
 * android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
 * android.permission.READ_SMS
 * android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
 * android.permission.SEND_SMS
 * android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
 * android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
 * com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
 * com.software.application.permission.C2D_MESSAGE

[ Responsible API calls for used Permissions ]
 * android/app/NotificationManager;->notify
 * android/content/Context;->sendBroadcast
 * android/content/Context;->startService
 * android/os/PowerManager$WakeLock;->acquire
 * android/os/PowerManager$WakeLock;->release
 * android/telephony/SmsManager;->sendTextMessage

[ Potentially dangerous Calls ]
 * getSystemService
 * HttpPost
 * sendSMS
```

Current output example:

```
[PotentiallydangerousCalls]
getSystemService
HttpPost
sendSMS
```

So it's a bit cleaner now...

Answer (score 1):

I will put some code if I have time, but here is a roadbook :

1) Write a function (CsvToObject) that take the path and name of a csv file and return a PSObject with a property with each [value]

- This function can take advantage of `switch ... case` PowerShell structure with  regex and file usage.

2) Take every *.csv file (`Get-ChildItem`) , call your function and pipe the result in `Export-CSV`

Answer (score 0):

Your current output example is structured like an ini file. This [Scripting Guy post on ini files](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/08/20/use-powershell-to-work-with-any-ini-file.aspx) might be useful. Some regex help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299893/powershell-regex-check-for-string-between-brackets).